# Uniquely left join many to many table

Tags: sql-server

I am using sqlserver and I have two table which contains below data. I need to select those matched rows without duplicate.

Table_A:

```
A_ID | Item_ID
--------------------
1    | 101
2    | 101
3    | 103
4    | 103
5    | 199
```

Table_B:

```
B_ID | Item_ID
--------------------
11    | 101
12    | 101
13    | 102
14    | 103
15    | 103
16    | 103
```

Expected Result:

```
A_ID | Item_ID | B_ID
----------------------
1    | 101     | 11
2    | 101     | 12
3    | 103     | 14
4    | 103     | 15
```

I tried:

```
SELECT A_ID, a.Item_ID, B_ID FROM Table_A a LEFT JOIN
Table_B b ON a.Item_ID = b.Item_ID
```

But it show all the possible records.

How can i display the expected result above?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me... Why are you leaving out, for example, `B_ID = 16`?

Comment: @MostyMostacho I am trying to display all the records that base on Table_A, as you can see Table_A contains 2 records with 103, so the expected result should display 2 records with Item_ID 103 only.

Comment: Yes, I get that part. However, I don't see what criteria you have chosen to keep `14` and `15` in the result and not `16`. Btw, after your edit now I don't understand why you're leaving out `199`... a left join is there to keep it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the result set you gave you want one unique record from B for each A, ignoring records in A for which there is no corresponding record in B. The following will work:

```
SELECT
    AValues.A_ID,
    AValues.Item_ID,
    BValues.B_ID
FROM
(SELECT
    A_ID,
    Item_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item_ID ORDER BY A_ID) ARowID
FROM    
    Table_A) AValues
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    B_ID,
    Item_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Item_ID ORDER BY B_ID) BRowID
FROM
    Table_B) BValues ON AValues.Item_ID = BValues.Item_ID AND AValues.ARowID = BValues.BRowID
```